# Revit API collector: Could not cast value:spaces to target_type:

Tags: python, revit-api, pyrevit

I don't understand why my code, which works fine with other revit categories:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import rpw
from rpw import revit, db, ui, DB, UI

dd1 = rpw.db.Collector(of_category='Spaces')
```

produces this error:

```
IronPython Traceback:
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Users\USTL02870\Dropbox\WSP Project local folders\PyRevit custom extensions folder\BTS-NY-BETA.extension\BTS-NY-BETA.tab\Beta Tools.panel\test1.pushbutton\beta1_script.py", line 16, in 
 File "C:\Users\USTL02870\AppData\Roaming\pyRevit-Master\pyrevitlib\rpw\db\collector.py", line 445, in __init__
 File "C:\Users\USTL02870\AppData\Roaming\pyRevit-Master\pyrevitlib\rpw\db\collector.py", line 464, in _collect
 File "C:\Users\USTL02870\AppData\Roaming\pyRevit-Master\pyrevitlib\rpw\db\collector.py", line 78, in apply
 File "C:\Users\USTL02870\AppData\Roaming\pyRevit-Master\pyrevitlib\rpw\db\collector.py", line 190, in process_value
 File "C:\Users\USTL02870\AppData\Roaming\pyRevit-Master\pyrevitlib\rpw\utils\coerce.py", line 149, in to_category
 File "C:\Users\USTL02870\AppData\Roaming\pyRevit-Master\pyrevitlib\rpw\db\builtins.py", line 134, in fuzzy_get
 File "C:\Users\USTL02870\AppData\Roaming\pyRevit-Master\pyrevitlib\rpw\db\builtins.py", line 107, in get
rpw.exceptions.RpwCoerceError: Could not cast value:spaces to target_type:
```

Answer (score 2):

What target type? If your target type is rooms, the explanation is provided by [The Building Coder](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com) discussion of [Collecting all Rooms on a Given Level](/blog/2017/03/events-uv-coordinates-and-rooms-on-level.html#6): You can't collect `Room` elements directly, because they are an artificial construct of the Revit API and do not exist natively inside of Revit. Therefore, you need to collect `SpatialElement` objects instead, the `Room` parent class, and post-process the results, e.g., cast them to rooms. See also [Accessing Room Data](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2011/11/accessing-room-data.html) and [Filtering for a Non-Native Class](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2010/08/filtering-for-a-nonnative-class.html).